# jquery css display block

Tags: jquery, menu, hover

I am trying to have a simply inline menu that when a certain element is hovered a row below appears offering a submenu. Unfortunately I can not get the sub menu to show when hovered. I have display none in the CSS and display block in the query, wondering if the CSS is overriding it somehow?

CSS

```
ul.main_menu  {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.main_menu li  {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline;
}
ul.main_menu li a  {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.submenu  {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
#services_menu  {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#services_menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#services_menu ul li  {
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline;
}
#service_menu ul li a  {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$("#servicebutton").hover(
  function () {
    $('#services_menu').css("display","block");
  }, 
  function () {
    $('#services_menu').css("display","none");
  });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="main_menu">
  <li id="homebutton"> <a href="#">Home </a></li>
  <li id="servicebutton"> <a href="#" >Services </a></li>
  <li id="packagebutton"> <a href="#" >Packages </a></li>
  <li id="spabutton"> <a href="#">The spa </a></li>
  <li id="productbutton"> <a href="#">Product </a></li>
  <li id="mebutton"> <a href="#">About Me </a></li>
  <li id="contactbutton"> <a href="#">Contact </a></li>
              <div class="submenu">
              <div id="services_menu">
              <ul>
                <li>Services1</li>
                <li>Services2</li>
                <li>Services3</li>
                <li>Services4</li>
                <li>Services5</li>
              </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might want to consider setting the color of the submenu's text to white in order to see it and set the hover handler after document-ready `$(function(){...})`...it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/yrXs4/).

Comment: What you are doing should technically work:

http://jsfiddle.net/e557z/

Make sure you are including jQuery and including the hover binding in document ready.

Comment: this might be useful for you http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jQuery's`hide()` and `show()` functions?

```
$('#services_menu').hide();
$('#services_menu').show();
```

Those functions take care of `display: block` and `display: none` for you and even can detect `display: inline` if needed.

EDIT:  As @undefined points out in the comments below, you might also be missing the document ready handler.  So all-in-all, your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#servicebutton").hover(
        function () {
            $('#services_menu').show();
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#services_menu').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: @undefined - Good call... I always assume all code is wrapped in it... :(

Comment: That seems to work in the jsfiddle but not on my website http://www.spencedesign.netau.net/lori/#

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/7VpyY/3/)

Your code seem's to work fine.

Try wraping your script in `ready` like this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#servicebutton").hover(
       function () {
        $('#services_menu').css("display","block");
       }, 
       function () {
         $('#services_menu').css("display","none");
       });
   });
```